# Newbie in need of searching, JSON

Tags: jquery, json, api, search

I am trying to find out about the per diem or lodging rates just by entering either a zip code, a city name or a state's name.  However when I try to do a broad search request, I get nothing.  I have searched through all the posts, but the focus more on search Google's API ... I am using another API or I may just be misunderstanding and the Google is the engine conducting the search ... please help ... below is my code.

Enter Search Term, theclick the **search** button!

search

$("#search").click(function(){ //search btn

```
$("#rs").empty();//div tag where results will display

$.getJSON('https://explore.data.gov/resource/perdiem.json?'+ $("#searchterm1").val(), function(data)
{ var states={},
            cities={},
            myArr=[];
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
            states[value.state]=1
            if (!cities[value.state])
                cities[value.state]={}
            if(!cities[value.state][value.city])
                cities[value.state][value.city]=0
            cities[value.state][value.city]++
        })
        $.each(sortedKeys(states),function(i,state){
            myArr.push('<input type="text" name=">'+city+"","+state+"/>")
            myArr.push('<input type="text" name=">'+zip+"","+city+"","+state+"/>")
            $.each(sortedKeys(cities[state]),function(i,city){

            })
        })
        $('.content').append(myArr.join(''))
    })      
})



 var Parent = document.getElementById("rs");
  for (var i = 0; i < result.response.docs.length; i++) {
    var thisResult = "<b>" + result.response.docs[i].title + "</b><br>" + result.response.docs[i].dateline
    + ", " + result.response.docs[i].text + "<br>";
    var NewDiv = document.createElement("div");
    NewDiv.innerHTML = thisResult;
    Parent.appendChild(NewDiv);
  }
});
```

});

-->

Comment: please follow proper rules when you ask questions. This will help your question to get better attention. refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error

Answer (score 0):

Here is javascript error

```
myArr.push('<input type="text" name=">'+city+"","+state+"/>")
```

Altho i never tried to search per diem, but your code should be

```
myArr.push('<input type="text" name=">'+city+'","'+state+'"/>')
```

Comment: Thank you showing me the correction with the myArr.push context, but I am still having problems trying to search the JSON API based upon user input ... like pull all the JSON data based upon the zip code the user enter ... here is the update code ... any assistance would be helpful       ................

Comment: Sample code part I:       
<input  id="fiscalyear" type="hidden" name="fiscalyear" value="2013">
zip:<input id="zip" type="text" name="zip">
city:<input id="city" type="text" name="city"><input  type="submit" value="search" id="submit" style="width:100px">
<div id="places" class="placesdata"></div>
<div class="content"></div> 
//script  
var myArr = [];
$('.submit').click(function($e){
      $e.preventDefault()e

Comment: Sample code part II: $.getJSON('https://explore.data.gov/resource/perdiem.json',function(data){
$.each(data, function(key, value)
{ myArr.push(+value.fiscalyear+value.city+value.zip)}
$('input#zip').val(data.zip);
$('input#city').val(data.city);
$('input#fiscalyear').val(data.fiscalyear); });    }    $('.content').html(myArr.join(''))
);  })  //end script